# Very speed mind and calm mind

Tags: vipassana, mind

With mindfulness experience  that  there is a mind operating  very speed and realized  not worth.  After little time of thinking get rid of uneasiness happens automatically .That leed to feel happiness. What was the state of mind at this stage of meditation?is it the stage where mind operates on it's own?Mindfulness  mind is very  calm  but feel like not worth attach to it even.

Answer (score 1):

You told so little information which could be many state.

1. The lowest state of the simple meditation of a person who can't ever do sitting meditation whole day through years.
2. The high state of a person who can do sitting meditation whole day through years simply.

Which one your are is depending on various information that you didn't told us. Calming, happiness,  feeling like not worth attach to it, etc. are not enough information to judge your state.

1. How long you sit per days?
2. Do you have the "instead characteristics of major characteristic and minor characteristic  (PaṭibhāgaNimitta for concentration meditation; Pure 3 characteristics and pure smallest realities for insight meditations are the instead object of Nimitta and Anubyañjana)"?
3. Do you realize that both meditations and Buddha's teaching are the only main path for your lives from now on.
4. etc.

We need more information from you  to consider of what you are.

Comment: What is patigaha nimittha?see oil lamp in the middle. Sometimes disc.

Answer (score 0):

There are many kinds of happiness or feelings.
The following Sutta explains all.

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.059.than.html